# How to get name of dataframe group?

Tags: dataframe, julia

When iterating over a `GroupedDataFrame`, how can one get the name/key of the group?

E.g. access what `a` equals for each group:

```
df = DataFrame(a=repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], outer=[2]),
                      b=repeat([2, 1], outer=[4]),
                      c=1:8);

gd = groupby(df, :a)

for g in gd
   #... do something with the dataframe and the key of the dataframe
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like iterating over a `pairs(dict)` to get both keys and values of a dictionary, you can iterate over `pairs(gd)` to get `GroupKey`s and values:

```
julia> for (k, g) in pairs(gd)
         println(k)
       end
GroupKey: (a = 1,)
GroupKey: (a = 2,)
GroupKey: (a = 3,)
GroupKey: (a = 4,)
```

This behaves like a `NamedTuple`, and has all the keys as `names` - in case you have multiple columns you have grouped by. In your case, you can access the value of `a` for a given group with `k.a`.